# Unable to get HTTP response in Worklight 6.2, 6.3

Tags: java, android, rest, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters

Error: WLNativeXHRPlugin$NativeXHRPostListener.onException

```
03-06 12:35:07.406: D/NONE(10503): Transfer failed, errors = {"invocationContext":null,"errorCode":"REQUEST_TIMEOUT","errorMsg":"Request timed out for http://192.168.85.1:10080/RestServiceCommunication/apps/services/api/RestServerCommunivation/android/query. Make sure the host address is available to the application (especially relevant for Android and iPhone apps)."}
03-06 12:35:07.526: E/com.worklight.androidgap.plugin.WLNativeXHRPlugin(10503): WLNativeXHRPlugin$NativeXHRPostListener.onException in WLNativeXHRPlugin.java:137 :: onException
03-06 12:35:07.526: E/com.worklight.androidgap.plugin.WLNativeXHRPlugin(10503): org.apache.http.conn.ConnectTimeoutException: Connect to /192.168.85.1:10080 timed out
03-06 12:35:07.526: E/com.worklight.androidgap.plugin.WLNativeXHRPlugin(10503):     at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:121)
03-06 12:35:07.526: E/com.worklight.androidgap.plugin.WLNativeXHRPlugin(10503):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:144)
03-06 12:35:07.526: E/com.worklight.androidgap.plugin.WLNativeXHRPlugin(10503):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
```

The device is android 4.3, 4.4.2, 5.02

Answer (score 0):

Per the error log, are you certain the backend is available?

- is it working in preview?
- are you sure the device is able to connect to the MobileFirst Server?
- Make sure the server is exposed to the public Internet
- Increase the procedure timeout (on both the application code and adapter procedure in the adapter XML)

Comment: In preview it's working, it's able to connect to mobile first server, it is exposed to public internet, I've even increased the timeout but still no luck in getting the data through device.

Comment: I am having the same issue on android device and it is also have same issue in preview.

I am using worklight 6.3. How should I resolve this problem.